# Simple PHP CURL request to Facebook API not working?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have a photo application where the user can create albums. My concern is that if they delete the album via facebook andthey try to upload another picture in that album, it's eaither not going to work or create a default album and upload it to that.

So what I was thinking was to check if the album exists before uploading a picture. Here's the code I have:

```
exec("curl https://graph.facebook.com/10150160401046994?access_token=i_have_a_access_token_here_but_i_dont_want_to_share_it", $hi);

print_r("$hi");
```

However, when outputting I just get "ARRAY". I really want to see what Facebook says just as if you went to the page.

Thanks in advance
Coulton

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there any possible reason you can't use curl for this?

```
$ch = curl_init('https://graph.facebook.com/10150160401046994?access_token=i_have_a_access_token_here_but_i_dont_want_to_share_it');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
var_dump(json_decode($response)); // if you want an array.
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Now how would I get an object from that? `$array = var_dump(json_decode($response)); echo "".$array['id']."";` doesn't work, it outputs the whole array.

Comment: For an array: $array = json_decode($response, 1), for an object: $object = json_decode($response) - var_dump($array); var_dump($objecT); to see them displayed.

Answer (score 2):

First problem, use PHP's [Curl library](http://php.net/curl). Let's stay away from `exec` if we can :P

Second, when converting and `Array` to a `String` the converted string is equal to `"Array"`. If you just want a quick dump of the information use `var_dump( $hi );`

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the method I used doesn't working and returns a blank array. `array(0) { }`